# 2-dimensional hue graph of array

Tags: graphical-output

## The Question

Given a two dimensional array, `o[][]`, create a 2-dimensional graph such that `o[xCoordinate][yCoordinate]` is the hue of the point at (xCoordinate, yCoordinate), and the value and saturation are always 100. Let the hue go from -50 to 50, where -50 and 50 are 0 and 100 respectively.

## Rules

- You may use any language you wish
- Lowest bytes wins
- Include seperate byte amount for points taken off from extra

## Extra

If you want extra points (or, less actually) you can include a snippit of code in the same language such that `o[x][y]` is equal to sin x · cos y, in less than 25 bytes more than your original snippit. Extra points removes 10 bytes from your score.

#### Example Language: 89 [79] (Extra: 113)

Comment: Fixed it, I meant "100"

Comment: On what scale? 0 to 100? (Same for the Hue. Does it go from 0 to 2 pi? From 0 to 360? From 0 to 1? From 0 to 100?)

Comment: The hue goes from -50 to 50, where -50 and 50 are 0 and 100 respectively.

Comment: What do you mean by "where -50 and 50 are 0 and 100 respectively"? Are they -50 and 50 or are they 0 and 100? The scale of value and saturation is also still not mentioned in the challenge.

Comment: Value and saturation stay at 100, so only color is affected. Also, say the output of sin x * cos x is 0, this would make the hue 50. If the output was -50, the hue would be 0, and if the output was 50, the hue would be 100.

Comment: When saying "equal to sin x · cos x", are you referring to the x in `o[x][y]` (or in Mathematica, `o[[x, y]]`)?

Comment: sorry, i mean sin x * cos y

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica: 68

```
Graphics@Raster@Reverse[List@@Hue[#/100]~ColorConvert~"RGB"&/@#&/@o]
```

Still figuring out the extra.

Comment: What does Mathematica not have a function for?

Comment: @Loovjo I've yet to be able to get it to make me a sandwich.